# Learning python Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, string-formatting

I am new to python and trying to learn the basic

just learned how to format string today and couldn't figure out what is wrong with this line of codes

```
data = ["Zac", "poor fella", 100]
format_string = "%s is a %s, his bank account has $%s."
print(format_string % data)
```

my goal is trying to print out "John is a poor fella, his bank account has $100."

But when I run it it came back with "Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Please let me know what I did wrong, thanks!

I tried putting parentheses in between format_string and data

Comment: The arguments must be provided as a tuple, not as a list. Use `data = (...)`, not `data = [...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `tuple` instead of `list` and use `%` to format the string:

```
data = ["Zac", "poor fella", 100]
print("%s is a %s, his bank account has $%s." % tuple(data))
```

**Result:**
*Zac is a poor fella, his bank account has $100.*

You could use modern *f-string* formatting:

```
data = ["Zac", "poor fella", 100]
print(f"{data[0]} is a {data[1]}, his bank account has ${data[2]}.")
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks! :))